# AngularJS - Check my implementation of resource factory

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, rest

Just starting out on AngularJS & js (being a backend developer) and this is the first Javascript MVC framework which I have ever worked on so please go easy...

I have a restful json API which I would like to consume using AngularJS.

In order to implement this, I have created two factories, one singular for when a controller needs to query the factory with an id, and a plural factory for when id is not required.

e.g. below:

Controller to list all products:

```
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, ProductsFactory) {
    $scope.products = [];

    init();
    function init()
    {
        $scope.products = ProductsFactory.query();
    }
});
```

Factories:

```
app.factory('ProductsFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/xxx/xxx/xxx/api/v1/product', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    });
});

app.factory('ProductFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/xxx/xxx/xxx/api/v1/product/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id' } },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' } }
    });
});
```

Question 1: Am I implementing the resource factory correctly?
Question 2: Is there a way of just using one factory for Products? e.g. allowing the factory to decide that id is not necessary for `query` and `create`, but is required for `show`, `update` and `delete` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use just 1 factory :

```
app.factory('ProductFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/xxx/xxx/xxx/api/v1/product/:id', { id : '@id'}, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' },     
    });
});
```

You don't need to specify the 'params' object to every requests. Defining it for the $resource is often enough (but if you want to overwrite it of course you can use it).

Notice that you don't need to define the CRUD methods since the $resource already implements them (as stated in the doc : http://docs.angularjs.or/api/ngResource.$resource).

At the moment, you just need to define a custom method update if you want to use "PUT" but a pull request is opened (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3416) and I hope we can expect to see it implemented soon.